# Rails-api with Mongoid in local gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rubygems, mongoid, database-connection

I have a `rails-api` project, which uses my own local gem for authorization purposes.
This gem should connect `MongoDB` to store users and tokens.

I cannot esablish connection with `MongoDB` using `Mongoid` and doing

`Mongoid.load!(yaml_dir, env)`

When I call any method from `Mongoid` (`load!`, `logger`) I got

`/Users/M/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/mongoid-1.0.6/lib/mongoid.rb:68:in 'method_missing': undefined method 'load!' for #<Mongoid::Config:0x000001049e10d8> (NoMethodError)`

How to connect with mongo from local gem?

Comment: This generally works for me, but I use a version of mongoid greater than 3.0. According to the old Mongoid 2.0 docs you should try the following in the initialization of your app `Mongoid.configure do |config|
  config.master = Mongo::Connection.new.db("godfather")
end`. But these are according to the Mongoid 2.0 docs and there is a good chance they won't work for your version. Since your version of mongoid isn't supported anymore, I highly recommend you upgrade to 3.0. And upgrade your version of rails while your'e at it to at least 3.2.13

Comment: I use Mongoid 4. I don't know why it installed mongoid 1 too.

Comment: You wouldn't be the first person to make that complaint. I think it by default downloaded mongoid 1 due to your version of rails. I think if you upgraded your version of rails and then stuck in `gem "mongoid", "~> 4.0.0.beta1"` in your gemfile you should be good to go

Comment: Yep. I changed that and it seems to be working right now.

Comment: Ok, I'll move the comment into the answer section so that this question isn't in the unanswered bin. Feel free to upvote ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to specify

`gem 'mongoid', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'`

in gem `Gemfile` and

`gem 'mongoid', '~>4.0.0.beta1', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'`

Rails `Gemfile`.

`gem.gemspec` has to have the following entries:

```
spec.add_runtime_dependency 'mongoid'
spec.add_runtime_dependency 'bson'
spec.add_runtime_dependency 'bson_ext'
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem is that the method isn't supported in the version of mongoid that your are using (in your case version 1.0.6)

It appears that based on your version of rails the mongoid gem downloaded a really old version. Once you upgrade your version of rails and stick in the following into your gemfile you're problem should be solved:
`gem "mongoid", "~> 4.0.0.beta1"`

Also, make sure to upgrade your version of mongoid once there is a stable version release (ie post-beta)